# Dynamically creating Radio Buttons and Assigning selected Values PHP

Tags: php, radio-button

Hi I am pretty new to PHP. I am trying to get the selected value from my radio button in PHP but I am unable to get the selected value. I have populated the values by connecting to my DB (MySQL) but I am unable to get the assigned value from the radio button. It always escapes the if condition and says "No Value Selected" and I am not able to assign the value and save it to my DB

Appreciate your help.

My index.php is as follows `

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['timein']=  time();
?>

<?php
include("config.php");
        $conn = mysqli_connect($dbHost, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbDatabase);
        $query_salutation_type='SELECT salutation_description FROM tbl_salutation;';
        $select_salutation_type=mysqli_query($conn, $query_salutation_type);

        while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($select_salutation_type))
        {
            echo '<input type="radio" name="salutation_description" value="'.$row1[0].'"/>'.$row1[0];

        }
?>
<html>
<body>        
 <form method="post" action="capture_data.php" >    
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form> 
    </body>
 </html>
```

`

My capture_data.php is as follows

```
  <?php 


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

if(isset($_POST['salutation_description']))
{
    $selected_val = $_POST['salutation_description'];
    echo "You have selected :" .$selected_val; 
}
 else 
{
    echo 'No Value Selected';
}
}
?>
```

[image: index.php]

Comment: The radio buttons aren't inside the form.

Answer (score 2):

The form only sends inputs that are between `<form>` and `</form>`. You're echoing the radio buttons before the `<form>`.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['timein']=  time();
?>
<html>
<body>        
 <form method="post" action="capture_data.php" >    

<?php
include("config.php");
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbHost, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbDatabase);
$query_salutation_type='SELECT salutation_description FROM tbl_salutation;';
$select_salutation_type=mysqli_query($conn, $query_salutation_type);

while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($select_salutation_type))
{
    echo '<input type="radio" name="salutation_description" value="'.$row1[0].'"/>'.$row1[0];

}
?>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use your radio button inside the `<form>` tag as:

**Modified Code:**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['timein']=  time();
?>
<html>
<body>        
<form method="post" action="capture_data.php" >  

<?php
include("config.php");
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbHost, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbDatabase);
$query_salutation_type='SELECT salutation_description FROM tbl_salutation;';
$select_salutation_type=mysqli_query($conn, $query_salutation_type);

while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($select_salutation_type))
{
echo '<input type="radio" name="salutation_description" value="'.$row1[0].'"/>'.$row1[0];

}
?>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['timein']=  time();
?>

<?php
include("config.php");
        $conn = mysqli_connect($dbHost, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbDatabase);
        $query_salutation_type='SELECT salutation_description FROM tbl_salutation;';
        $select_salutation_type=mysqli_query($conn, $query_salutation_type);
$radioHtml = "";
        while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($select_salutation_type))
        {
            $radioHtml.= '<input type="radio" name="salutation_description" value="'.$row1[0].'"/>'.$row1[0];

        }
?>
<html>
<body>        
 <form method="post" action="capture_data.php" >
       <?php echo $radioHtml; ?>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form> 
    </body>
 </html>
```

keep radio buttons within your form

Answer (score 0):

Hi Lad try to relocate the while loop inside the form tag of your HTML. Like the example below. :D

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['timein']=  time();
?>

<?php
include("config.php");
        $conn = mysqli_connect($dbHost, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbDatabase);
        $query_salutation_type='SELECT salutation_description FROM tbl_salutation;';
        $select_salutation_type=mysqli_query($conn, $query_salutation_type);
?>
<html>
<body>        
 <form method="post" action="capture_data.php" >    
<?php
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($select_salutation_type))
        {
            echo '<input type="radio" name="salutation_description" value="'.$row1[0].'"/>'.$row1[0];

        }
?>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form> 
    </body>
 </html>
```